# Does this equation have positive integer solutions?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, sums-of-squares

The only solution I can find for $a^2 + b^2 + c^2 = d^2 + e^2 + f^2$   is $a=0$, $b=0$, $c=0$, $d=0$, $e=0$, $f=0$.  Are there any positive integer solutions?  Any where none of $a,b,c,d,e,f$ are equal?

Comment: Welcome to math.stackexchange! Try to use LaTeX to format your question. Also what have you tried?

Comment: $a=b=c=d=e=f=1$.

Comment: $A^2+b^2=d^2$ and $c^2=e^2+f^2$ is a start...  Also, any combination where $a=d, b=e, c=f$, like $1^2+2^2+3^3=1^2+2^2+3^2$

Comment: I guess my question is poorly formulated. I am looking for solutions where a, b , c, d, e and f are not equal.

Comment: @Sherif: Please edit your Question accordingly.  And see [this OEIS entry](http://oeis.org/A063691).

Comment: Perhaps the first (slightly) interesting example is $27 = 3^2 + 3^2 +3^2 = 5^2 + 1^2 + 1^2$, though imposing a condition that none of the parameters are equal excludes this.

Answer (score 6):

Solving $a^2 + b^2 + c^2 = d^2 + e^2 + f^2$ has many many (boring) positive integer solutions.

Choose any bijection  $\theta: \{a,b,c\} \to \{d,e,f\}$. Then, choose any positive integer values for $\{a,b,c\}$.

It must be true that $a^2 + b^2 +c^2 = \theta(a)^2 + \theta(b)^2 + \theta(c)^2 = d^2 + e^2 + f^2.$ As stated though, these are all pretty boring, and probably not quite what you're looking for. For less "boring" solutions, combining some known Pythagorean triples could help.

For example, $3^2 + 4^2 = 5^2$. Meanwhile $8^2 + 15^2 = 17^2$ (I think, somebody else can fact-check this triple). Thus,

$(3^2+4^2)+17^2 = 5^2 + (8^2+15^2)$

Comment: In other words, combining any two Pythagorean triples gives a solution.

Comment: This allows us to form solutions $a^2 + b^2 + c^2 = d^2 + e^2 +f^2$ where none of $a,b,c,d,e,f$ are equal, a "strong" version of the problem.  Somewhat smaller solutions can be found that are not of this form.  I think the least integer that can be represented as the sum of three distinct positive squares in two ways is $62 = 6^2 + 5^2 + 1^2 = 7^2 + 3^2 + 2^2$.

Answer (score 4):

You are asking, in a nontrivial vein, how many ways a positive integer can be represented as the sum of three squares.

It is [widely known](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Integer_as_Sum_of_Three_Squares) ([related](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/227672/sum-of-three-squares-need-to-check-the-expressions-with-the-lower-powers-of-4)) which positive integers admit such representations.  The question of how many sum of three squares representations exist for a given positive integer was explored by P. Bateman (1951) in a lengthy paper freely available from the AMS:

[On the Representations of a Number as the Sum of Three Squares](http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1951-071-01/S0002-9947-1951-0042438-4/S0002-9947-1951-0042438-4.pdf)

and the classical literature on the subject (Dickson, Landau, Hardy, etc.) is well surveyed there up to the time.

In Dave Rusin's [collection of posts](http://www.math.niu.edu/~rusin/known-math/95/three.sq) related to this topic, we find him stating this interesting characterization:

> In how many ways may one represent a given
>   integer n as a sum of three squares? Eichler noted that for n
>   squarefree, the number of ways is, as noted above, zero is n=7 mod 8.
>   If n=3 mod 8, he showed the number of representations is 12h, where
>   h is the class number of the field Q(sqrt(-n)). Otherwise, the number
>   of representations is 24h.

Also Math.SE related: [Representability as a Sum of Three Positive Squares or Non-negative Triangular Numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/26570/representability-as-a-sum-of-three-positive-squares-or-non-negative-triangular-n).

A fast randomized algorithm for finding an integer solution $n = x^2 + y^2 + z^2$ was the topic of [Rabin and Shallit algorithm](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/483101/rabin-and-shallit-algorithm).  The discussion turns up an interesting connection to Hardy and Littlewoods's Conjecture H, about the number of ways to express $n = x^2 + p$ as the sum of a square and a prime.

Answer (score 0):

Surprisingly, there are so many solutions that satisfy the equation!  Here are solutions (having all positive integer solutions)

1. $a = d$, $b = e$, $c = f$
2. $a = e$, $b = f$, $c = d$ (since addition is commutative)
3. $a = f$, $b = e$, $c = d$
4. $a = f$, $b = d$, $c = e$
5. $a = e$, $b = d$, $c = f$

...and so much more!